# Type inference fail

Tags: c#, type-inference

I have the following case of type inference "failing" (at least failing for what I wish it did). Basically, I have a method that accepts an array of a generic type. I need that array to be typed of the anonymous object, but type inference fails to do so.

```
    private void foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Object>[] propertySelector) { }

    public void Main()
    {
        var peeps = new[]
        {
            new {FirstName = "Taco", LastName = "King"},
            new {FirstName = "Papa", LastName = "Georgio"}
        };

        foo(peeps, new[]
        {
            an => an.FirstName, //Error cannot infer type of "an"
            an => an.LastName   //Error cannot infer type of "an"
        });
    }
```

I believe the reason is because the array type is inferred from its contents, not its context. It would seem this makes it impossible to use anonymous types in this context.

Any idea on a way around this?

Answer (score -1):

In the example given, you can change `propertySelector` to a `params` argument and then pass in each function individually instead of as an array. If you can't use `params` for some reason, then a helper function like this will work:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the use of type inference to get selector functions for the type of an enumerable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the enumerable.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerable">The enumerable.</param>
    /// <param name="selectors">A set of selectors to return.</param>
    /// <returns>The selectors passed in.</returns>
    public static Func<T, Object>[] GetSelectors<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
        params Func<T, Object>[] selectors)
    {
        return selectors;
    }
```

So your example would become:

```
private void foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Object>[] propertySelector) { }

public void Main()
{
    var peeps = new[]
    {
        new {FirstName = "Taco", LastName = "King"},
        new {FirstName = "Papa", LastName = "Georgio"}
    };

    foo(peeps, GetSelectors(peeps, an => an.FirstName, an => an.LastName));
}
```

Comment: Did you just ask a question so you could answer it yourself?

Comment: Yes wt*, and just answered right away. I think the guy has 2 accounts and just answers himself with the other one to get point...lame

Comment: @AnnArbor87 I have one account and yes, I answered my own question. And no, I'm not doing it for points. If you've ever asked a question you'll see its an option here. I answered it myself to help me remember this for future situations and in case it could potentially help anyone else.